# Powering board and charging coin cell at the same time

Tags: batteries, atmega

Here is what I have:

- 2035 coin cell battery
- ATmega328

I want to have an ability to plug micro/mini usb cord and power circuit from usb and charge battery. Circuit has extremely low power consumption (almost a month on 110mAh). Right now I'm swapping batteries. Is there a way to add charging ability?

I know I need to connect them in parallel, but I have hard time comprehending how it looks on schematics.

Comment: Is the 2032 rechargeable? If so, what chemistry?

Comment: Yes, it's Li-ion. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/10319

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fellow created a USB charger for those. If you are working with a custom board, you can integrate his schematic into yours:

http://chasingtrons.com/main/2012/3/26/cr2450-coin-cell-charger.html

From the [MCP73832 datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20001984g.pdf):
Check out the "typical application"

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZ7tNK.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This delivers 5V to LOAD when powered by USB; if LOAD is an Arduino, that not a problem. This is compatible with chargers that go Hi-Z when finished charging. The Schottky will protect the battery from the 5V and minimize loss while the device runs off the battery. The other diode is less critical, but might as well be Schottky too.

Comment: Is there a charge controller chip that will take the battery off charge when it's full again?

Comment: Yeah, I have charger like that. I just can't figure out how to combine them together.

Comment: Rolled-back and revised schematic.

Comment: This is a simple design; there are power-path controllers (TI, Linear) that can do all of the above and have integrated boost converters. They would provide LOAD with a steady 5V, regardless of the power source.